# iOS - How to set imageview of a parent view controller through child container?

Tags: swift, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I am currently using a container view and I want to change the value of parent view controller imageView through child view controller using delegates, but it always returns `nil`.

```
import UIKit

protocol updateImage {
    func userIsDone(image:UIImage)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, updateImage{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!
    var image = UIImage(named: "hello.png")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image=self.image
    }

    func userIsDone(image: UIImage) {
        self.image=image
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "containerChild"{

            let nextView = segue.destinationViewController as! ControllerChild
            nextView.image=self.image
            nextView.delegate=self
        }
    }
}

class ControllerChild:UIViewController{

    var image=UIImage(named: "newhello.png")
    var delegate: updateImage? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func changeImage(sender:UIButton){

        if(delegate != nil){
            self.delegate!.userIsDone(self.image!)
            print("I am Called!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than posting an image of code, please post the actual code in your question.

Comment: posted the code. @Fahim

Comment: Thank you :) Taking a look now. Will post if I have an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you have prepareForSegue if a VC has a container which holds another VC as a child. Care to post the storyboard flow ?

Comment: Because i have to add multiple containers and they will be called upon segmented action. can you help on it. @OhadM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
nextView.image = image
```

And change the `userIsDone` function to:

```
func userIsDone(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
}
```

[image: hello]

As side notes:

- In Swift you don't need to use `self` outside of blocks/closures. For example, you don't need to `self.imageView.image = self.image` -- just `imageView.image = image` will do.
- Protocols should be upper-cased, like `UpdateImage` (instead of `updateImage`).
- You don't need that extra `.png` to reference images, just the title, E.g.: `"hello"`.

Apple describes Swift code conventions in their [awesome Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-0-1/id881256329?mt=11).

Here is the code, refactored (Swift 3):

```
import UIKit

protocol UpdateImageProtocol {
    func userIsDone(image: UIImage)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UpdateImageProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var image = UIImage(named: "hello")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userIsDone(image: image!)
    }

    func userIsDone(image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerChild" {
            let nextView = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
            nextView.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    var image = UIImage(named: "newHello")
    var delegate: UpdateImageProtocol?

    @IBAction func changeImage(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.userIsDone(image: image!)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you the problem is solved with this. can you please tell how to change container view controller upon segmented action. @backslash-f

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I understood your question... What exactly you would like to achieve? (I suggest creating another separate question with more details, things can get confusing in these comments fields).